Allowing 2 Authorisation Headers in a custom connector in power automate
Hoping for some help. for reference I have read Power Automate Custom Connector Authorization Header and this doesn't work as required
I have an app proxy sitting between power automate and the api services I need to connect to. the proxy is Azure AD, and the API is standard oAuth
Step 1 of requesting an access token through the proxy is fine. My custom connector works correctly and I can pull off the access token for the API.
Step 2 however breaks. I need a Authorization header to get through the oauth of the Azure AD, but I also need a Authorization header for the oauth of the webapi.
I have tried doing a manual override as suggested in the above post, but that happens BEFORE the AD Auth, so I end up getting blocked at the proxy stage.
Ideally I would need a way of using the Auth Header to pass Azure AD, then update the header via an override to the API header to get past the security there.
Anyway to do this, or is there a better way in general to approach this issue.
